# como unir varios registros en una sola fila pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Lo que intento hacer es generar un archivo parecido a esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya tengo el rango de dias y el nombre de los dias, y estos los paso a excel, pero al querer parsear la informacion en una sola linea es donde me quedo atorado

este es el resultado que me regresa mi funcion TimeClock :    `[('05-31-2021', '13:57:48'), ('05-31-2021', '09:56:02'), ('06-01-2021', '21:32:15'), ('06-01-2021', '06:04:33'), ('06-02-2021', '10:02:09'), ('06-03-2021', '20:42:56'), ('06-03-2021', '09:28:37'), ('06-05-2021', '18:06:06'), ('06-05-2021', '07:58:21')]`

```
class HorariosChoferes():

    def __init__(self):
        init = datetime.strptime('05-31-2021', '%m-%d-%Y')
        end = datetime.strptime('06-05-2021', '%m-%d-%Y')
        RangeDates = [init + timedelta(days=d) for d in range((end - init).days + 1)]
        datesNames = list(map(lambda date: pd.Timestamp(date).day_name(), RangeDates))
        operadores = self.getEmployeds()
        book = xlsxwriter.Workbook('ReporteChecadas.xlsx')
        sheet = book.add_worksheet('Asistencia')
        for oper in operadores:
            employed = self.getProyect(oper[1])
            employed['#'] = oper[1].strip()
            employed['Nombre'] = oper[2].strip()
            employed['Departamento'] = oper[3].strip()
            employed['Status'] = 'Activo' if oper[4] == 'AC' else 'Inactivo'
            dates = self.TimeClock(oper[0], init, end)
            print(employed)
            
            for _date in RangeDates:
                _date = datetime.strftime(_date, '%m-%d-%Y')
                arr = np.array(dates)                
                df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['fecha', 'hora'])
                df['fecha_exacta'] = df.fecha + ' ' + df.hora
                df['fecha_exacta'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fecha_exacta'], format='%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
                mascara_fecha = df.fecha == _date
                df_2 = df[mascara_fecha]


                mascara_min = (df_2['fecha_exacta'].min() == df_2['fecha_exacta'])
                mascara_max = (df_2['fecha_exacta'].max() == df_2['fecha_exacta'])

                df_2 = df_2[(mascara_min | mascara_max)
                            ].sort_values(by="fecha_exacta")
                
                dfgroup = df_2.groupby(['fecha'])['hora'].apply(
                    ','.join).reset_index()

                for i in dfgroup.index:
                    fechas = dfgroup['hora'][i]
                    fechas = fechas.split(',')
                    horasTrabajadas = datetime.strptime(fechas[1], '%H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(fechas[0], '%H:%M:%S') if len(fechas) > 1 else 'Checadas Incompletas'
                    fechas.append(str(horasTrabajadas))
                    print(fechas)

def getRangeMergeNames(self, range):
    data = {
        0: 'G2:I2',
        1: 'J2:L2',
        2: 'M2:O2',
        3: 'P2:R2',
        4: 'S2:U2',
        5: 'V2:X2',
        6: 'Y2:AA2',
        7: 'G2:I2',
        8: 'G2:I2',
        9: 'G2:I2',
        10: 'G2:I2',
        11: 'G2:I2'
    }

    return data[range]

def getRangeMergeDates(self, range):
    data = {
        0: 'G3:I3',
        1: 'J3:L3',
        2: 'M3:O3',
        3: 'P3:R3',
        4: 'S3:U3',
        5: 'V3:X3',
        6: 'Y3:A32',
        7: 'G3:I3',
        8: 'G3:I3',
        9: 'G3:I3',
        10: 'G3:I3',
        11: 'G3:I3'
    }

    return data[range]

def TimeClock(self, pin, init, end):
    with conexion.cursor() as cursor:
        consulta = f"SELECT \
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Date],110) AS Fecha, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Date],108) AS Hora \
        FROM \
            TChecadas t \
        WHERE \
            User_PIN = {pin} \
            AND [Date] BETWEEN '{datetime.strftime(init, '%Y-%m-%d')} 00:00:00' AND '{datetime.strftime(end, '%Y-%m-%d')} 23:59:59' \
        ORDER BY \
            Fecha, Hora DESC"
        cursor.execute(consulta)
        res = cursor.fetchall()
    return res
```

esto es lo que tengo hasta el final

```
{'Proyecto': 'FLEXTRONICS MANUFACTURING', 'Coordinador': 'JESUS MANUEL HERNANDEZ', '#': '6011', 'Nombre': 'Ortiz Gonzalez Lucas Rafael', 'Departamento': 'CRUCE', 'Status': 'Activo'}
['09:56:02', '13:57:48', '4:01:46']
['06:04:33', '21:32:15', '15:27:42']
['10:02:09', 'Checadas Incompletas']
['09:28:37', '20:42:56', '11:14:19']
['07:58:21', '18:06:06', '10:07:45']
```

cualquier comentarios seria de ayuda, de ante mano los agradezco

Comment: donde esta tu función `TimeClock`?, no lo veo en tu clase

Comment: al final es solo una consulta, no mas, pero si necesitan la info con gusto, se modifico el codigo

Comment: lo que te devuelve esa consulta es una lista con tupla `[('05-31-2021', '13:57:48')...]`, verdad?

Comment: asi es, para eso en el codigo utilizo el np.array

Comment: Quieres que te lo devuelva en un solo valor, así `['05-31-2021 13:57:48'...]`?

Comment: me doy cuenta que una solucion facil puede ser uniendo los resultados

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción sería sustituir las comas por un espacio en blanco, con la función replace

```
cells.Replace(","," ")
```